# What kind of features does each node have as an input graph to a graph neural network?

Tags: classification, geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks, features, graphs

What kind of features does each node have as an input graph to a graph neural network? For example, we want to do image classification with GNN, what are the features of each pixel? Or if anyone could send me a link to implementing GNN on an example I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Applying GNNs to images can be realized in different ways. If you *only* substitute a visual ConvNet by a GNN, then the pixel values would be the same as what goes into a ConvNet. The only difference will be the input format. Whereas a ConvNet gets inputs of shape `[batch, height, width, channels]`, a GNN would receive a list of pixels `[batch, n_pixels, channels]` together with an adjacency list that contains the structural information (Each pixel may have 8 neighbors and a selfloop except for the pixels at the boarders).

So basically the features doesn't change, what changes is the format of the data. For a clean library of GNNs you can checkout [DeepGraphLibrary](https://www.dgl.ai/), they have tutorials on how to use their library. If you want to see a simplified standalone implementation, you can checkout [this code](https://github.com/tkipf/pygcn/blob/1600b5b748b3976413d1e307540ccc62605b4d6d/pygcn/layers.py). His repository also contains more nice implementations.

Comment: Thanks! helped a lot